# Display the size of an arraylist to a textview

Tags: android, textview

I want to display the size of ArrayList to a textview.

```
Textview textView;
ArrayList<Integer> mList = new ArrayList<>();
if(mList.size() < 7)
      {
         mList.add(1);
         mList.add(2);
         mList.add(3);
      }
textView.setText(mList.size());
```

It is giving me Exception:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2
```

Comment: maybe you need change code to:
textView.setText(String.valueOf(mList.size()));

Comment: yes its working now. thanks a ton hehe i was not even aware of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use..

```
textView.setText(""+mList.size());
```

or

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(mList.size()));
```

or

```
textView.setText(mList.size().toString());
```

mark my answer accepted.